# Timeout issues in Protractor e2e tests during TeamCity build

Tags: jasmine, teamcity, protractor

I have a TeamCity configuration that deploys a build onto the QA Server and after it succeeds, it runs Protractor e2e tests.
I can run the tests manually from the checkout directory and they succeed, but on TeamCity they just time out (I've increased the time out threshold to 3 mins and they now take 3 minutes before timing out).

The exception I'm seeing is:

```
[should find all page controls] [Test Error Output]
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was: 

    Protractor.get(http://[QA SERVER]/#/) - reset url
        at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule 
        at [object Object].Protractor.executeScript_ 
        [...]
    A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
    The last active task was: 
    unknown
    [17:27:00][should find all page controls] Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
    [17:27:00]
    [should find all page controls] Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1782:23)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
```

I execute protractor as a Command Line -> Executable (`protractor`) and parameters are `protractor.conf.ci.js`.

The contents of my protractor config file are:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: "jasmine2",
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://[local server path]/',
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
    },
    specs: [
        'ui/*.uispec.js'
    ],
    onPrepare: function () {
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.TeamCityReporter());
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? It looks like something is blocking the execution, but Windows Firewall is disabled and again, the same tests run just fine if executed manually (using the same user account TeamCity agents use).

Thanks!